# backbone.js not appending elements, still the data console properly

Tags: backbone.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Backbone.js - change not triggering while the name change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453219/backbone-js-change-not-triggering-while-the-name-change)

In my following function, console show the datas, but nothing is appending to body tag, any one find me the issue..

my json :

```
[
    {name:'student4'},
    {name:'student5'},
    {name:'student6'}
]
```

code :

```
    (function($){   
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults:{
    name:'default name'
  }
});

var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model:model,
  url: 'data/names.json'
});



var itemViews = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagname:'li',
  render:function(){
    this.$el.html(this.model.get('name'));
    return this;
  }  
})

var view = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $("#contacts"),
  initialize:function(){
    this.collection = new collection();
    this.collection.on("reset", this.render, this);
    this.collection.fetch();
  },
  render:function(){
    var that = this;
    _.each(this.collection.models, function(item){
      that.renderName(item);
    })
  },
  renderName:function(item){
    var itemView = new itemViews({model:item});
    this.$el.append(itemView.render().el); //nothing rendering
  }
});


var stView = new view();

})(jQuery)
```

Comment: At which place do you console.log the collection? I am afraid your JSON data to be parsed into a collection must be like `[{name:'student4'},{name:'student5'},...]` without the extra `{names:[]}`

Comment: i tried, no luck. especially on each, i consoled nothing is appear, but in case if i simply console the collection it show the datas, in case of request data show the object as well

Comment: I would try doing .fetch().then(function(){ that.render()});

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be in these two lines:

```
this.collection.fetch(); //it seems it's not fetching;
this.render();
```

`Collection.fetch` is an asynchronous operation. By the time you `render` your view, the request has not yet returned, so your collection is empty. Try binding the render method to the collections `reset` event instead:

```
collection.on("reset", this.render, this);
this.collection.fetch();
```

Comment: i updated, but the render function not at all called

Comment: @3gwebtrain, changed my answer slightly. The previous version should've worked as well, but there were some complexities thay may have caused it to fail. The `reset` event is simpler.

Comment: i updated the coding, still not work. let me update the hole code again for your view. if possible can you put me on fiddle

Comment: There may be some problem with the html. See if you do have an element with `id="contacts"`.