# Backbone.js - change not triggering while the name change

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

In my backbone function, while the name get change the change function not at all triggering.. any one suggest me the right way to get it.. (actually i need to get changed stuff and need to update);

code :

```
    (function($){

var list = {};

list.model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults:{
    name:'need the name'
  },
  initialize:function(){
    this.bind('change:name', function(model) {
        console.log('Model->change()', model);
    });
  }
});

list.collect = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model:list.model,
  url : 'data/names.json',
  initialize:function(){
    this.fetch({update:true});
    this.keepUpdate();
  },
  keepUpdate:function(){
    var that = this;
    var updateData = function(){
      that.fetch({update:true});
      myTimeout = setTimeout(updateData,10000);
    }
    var myTimeout = setTimeout(updateData,10000);
  }
});


list.view = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize:function(){
    this.collection = new list.collect();
    this.collection.on("update", this.render, this);
    this.collection.bind("change:name", function(model, attributes){
      console.log(model,attributes,'property changed'); // this is not triggering at all..
    });
  },
  render:function(data){
    _.each(this.collection.models, function(data){
      //console.log(data.get('name')); it works fine
    })
  },
  updateName:function(){
    console.log('updated called');
  }
});

var newView = new list.view();    

})(jQuery)
```

Comment: Proper title please, summarizing the question.

Comment: edit your title. mention your problem there. title is meant for that, not the effort you put up on it

Comment: Please don't keep spamming the same question over and over again. This is the third time you ask the same question today.

Comment: If you want to increase the exposure you can put a bounty on the question, but the most obvious would be to improve the clarity of the question, especially if you are looking for a "clear" answer.

Comment: I suggest you take time to read the documentation for Collection.fetch: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch . This is the fourth time you open the same question, and in each one you try a different, incorrect way of fixing the same thing. The documentation tells you what options the `fetch` method accepts, and also which events it triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collection.fetch doesn't trigger the `change` event. You only get the `reset` event. If you need more granular events, consider calling [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) with the options `{update:true}`.

```
that.fetch({update:true});
```

That will trigger `change` event for every model that was already in the collection, and `add` if the model was previously not in the collection.

Comment: nope, i unable to follow you.. can you update my code please.. i am very sorry to say this.

Comment: @3gwebtrain, I edited my answer to be slightly more clear (wrote the original one the phone). But no, I am very sorry to say, I can't update your code for you.

Comment: let me update my total function again.. i am not get triggered by change event still..

Comment: @3gwebtrain, that's because there is not such thing as an `update` event... maybe if you actually read the answer and the corresponding (linked) documentation, you might have a higher chance of success.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing keepUpdate from the collection and put a setTimeout in the initialize function of the view at the end. I suggest that fetch is called from the view as well as this.collection.fetch() instead of the collection's initialize function. Makes your code more reusable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. What are you trying to achieve ?

I don't think that fetch accepts `{add:true}` as a parameter (I just checked the source code and it does not appear anywhere).

When `fetch` completes, it only triggers a `reset` event (not an `add`). You should listen to that if you want to do something when the content of the collection changes. You can also simplify listen to `change`.